# Why isn't this Vlookup Working? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is be able to double click a model number in a list box and then use an Hlookup to find the value in the actual list in a separate location. Eventually a simple calculation will get carried out, but I am stuck on this little bugger.

Just for some additional information Pricelist is the name a gave for the table containing model # and price and ListModel is the name of the list box.

```
Private Sub ListModel_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim perDiscountRate As Double
Dim PerDiscountPrice As Currency
Dim PriceList As String

perDiscountRate = InputBox("What is the discount rate", "Discount Calculator", "10") / 100
Application.Workbooks("T6-EX-E1D.xlsm").Worksheets("Computers").Range("c6:c8").Value = perDiscountRate

perDiscountRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("ListModel.Selected",   PriceList, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: `HLOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP`? You've got one in your title and one in your code.

Comment: what is `"ListModel.Selected"`?

Comment: You are not doing the lookup correctly. This link might help you get un-stuck: [http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Vlookup.html].

Comment: My bad, its a Vlookup.

Comment: ListModel is the name of the list box and what I am trying to do is have the item that gets double clicked on be the value that is looked up.

Comment: You have PriceList as a string but it needs to be a range. You need to pass a range to the second param of a Vlookup

Comment: Hi @Donoghue do you know the correct way to call out 'the clicked on' data variable? I keep getting an error that reads argument not optional and it highlights selected. I have also removed the quotations from Listmodel.selected

Comment: Please provide a sample screenshot of the data.

Comment: Zack, then consider editing your title to fix it. Also, this question isn't about the VBE so consider removing that from the title.

Answer (score 0):

if I guess your aim correctly you would use

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Application.Workbooks("T6-EX-E1D.xlsm").Worksheets("Computers")
With Me.ListModel
    PerDiscountPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.List(.ListIndex), sht.Range("PriceList"), 2, 0)
End With
```

where I supposed that "PriceList" was the 'named range' in "Computers" worksheet of "T6-EX-E1D.xlsm" workbook.

if not, just change references as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I was able to get the code to work. Here is what it looked like.

```
Private Sub ListModel_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim perDiscountRate As Double
Dim PerDiscountPrice As Currency
Dim PriceList As Range
Dim Org As Worksheet

Set Org = Application.Workbooks("T6-EX-E1D.xlsm").Worksheets("Computers")


perDiscountRate = InputBox("What is the discount rate", "Discount Calculator", "10") / 100
Application.Workbooks("T6-EX- E1D.xlsm").Worksheets("Computers").Range("c6:c8").Value = perDiscountRate
PerDiscountPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListModel,  Range("PriceList"), 2)

Application.Workbooks("T6-EX-E1D.xlsm").Worksheets("Computers").Range("d6:d8").Value = PerDiscountPrice



End Sub
```

I was over complicating the first argument in the Vlookup by putting ListModel.selected. Just using the name ListModel was enough.

Best,
Zack